# creating file from sql data to csv in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule4

I need to create file from SQL database and load data into CSV file. After CSV file generated successfully, need to transfer it to another sftp location.

Comment: What is exactly the question or the problem you are having?

Comment: I need to generate CSV from SQL data using Mule 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are already familiar with [Mule 4 applications](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/mule-app-dev) and [flows](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/flow-component). In a flow you can query the database using the [Database connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.8/), use the Transform component to write a [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave) transformation to a CSV ([output application/csv](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-csv)), then use the [SFTP connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.3/) to write the file to the SFTP server.

You should get familiar with how each component from the documentation to be able to write the database query, the transformation and the SFTP transfer.

Comment: How much record volume we can handle using this?

Comment: That would depend on streaming and the resources available to the runtime. You should perform load testing to see how it behaves.

Comment: So I need to enable streaming while writing file? Thank you for help..

Comment: In Mule 4 streaming is usually the default. It depends on the connectors.

Comment: Hi Aled,  Do we need to batch job from sql to csv? using batch job helps or not?

Comment: It is not required. It depends on your requirements. That's outside the scope of this question.